# Angular directives using their own text content in isolate scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm making a custom angular directive that shows an image when you mouseover a certain word or thumbnail.  This directive matches elements with the attribute `showImage`.  For example:

`<span showImage="mountain">mountain</span>`

It seems like the easiest way to do this would be to register event listeners on mouseover and mouseout in the directive's `link` attribute, but these listeners are registered without triggering the digest cycle.  So yeah, I could add `scope.$apply()`, but this seems inelegant and there's probably a better way.

Then I came upon templates with the transclude option, which seem like they might be closer to what I want.  But here, I found two problems.  First, I don't want to wrap my text/thumbnail in another element, I just want to add some event listeners to it.  My other problem is more complicated: I want to make the vaule of `showImage` optional, as in:

`<span showImage>mountain</span>`

This should have the same effect as the first example.  If the attribute has no value, I want it to default to the value of the text inside the HTML element.  With directives, I can set an isolate scope using the attributes of the element, but there doesn't seem to be a way to set anything to the value of the inner text.  Something like this:

```
.directive('showImage', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      showImage: 'textContent'
    },
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
  };
});
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: although deprecated, you may want to look at the `replace` flag on the directive definition object https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object. As for the optional text, one way would be to have the showImage directive draw the text instead. i.e `<span showImage='mountain'></span>` and have the template be responsible for where the text is shown

Comment: Yeah, I did find `replace`, but since it's deprecated (and seemingly without a proper alternative?) I wanted to try to avoid it.  Also, yeah, that's not a bad idea, making the text content optional rather than the attribute value.

Comment: @codebreaker It is marked as deprecated because it doesn't conform with Web Components paradigm and won't be available in 2.0. There are no plans to remove it from 1.x.